# UPDATED: Bash + Awk : Print first X(dynamic) columns and always last column

Tags: bash, awk

```
  #file test.txt

  a b c 5    
  d e f g h 7
  gg jj 2
```

Say X = 3  I need the output like this:

```
   #file out.txt
   a b c 5
   d e f 7
   gg jj 2
```

NOT this:

```
a b c 5
d e f 7
gg jj 2 2 <--- WRONG
```

I've gotten to this stage:

```
cat test.txt | awk ' { print $1" "$2" "$3" "NF } '
```

Comment: `awk` can read files without needing to `cat` them and send through a pipe. The idiomatic technique is `awk '{...}' file1` or `awk '{...}' file1 file2` etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're unsure of the total number of fields, then one option would be to use a loop:

```
awk '{ for (i = 1; i <= 3 && i < NF; ++i) printf "%s ", $i; print $NF }' file
```

The loop can be avoided by using a ternary:

```
awk '{ print $1, $2, (NF > 3 ? $3 OFS $NF : $3) }' file
```

This is slightly more verbose than [the approach suggested by 123](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34629047/updated-bash-awk-print-first-xdynamic-columns-and-always-last-column/34629594#comment57004483_34629167) but means that you aren't left with trailing white space on the lines with three fields. `OFS` is the Output Field Separator, a space by default, which is what `print` inserts between fields when you use a `,`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `$` combined with `NF` :

```
cat test.txt | awk ' { print $1" "$2" "$3" "$NF } '
```

Comment: or use an Output Field Separator: `awk '{OFS=" "; print $1,$2,$3,$NF}' file`

Comment: @Cyrus Thats the default OFS anyway, no need to set it.

Comment: @123: Yes, this is okay: `awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$NF}' file`. Thank you.

Comment: @cyrus no the last line is wrong the number 2 is repeated twice

Comment: @user914584  `awk '{print $1,$2,$3,$4?$NF:""}'`

Comment: @123 that's a more succinct way to do it, although I would recommend enclosing the ternary in parentheses.

Comment: @TomFenech No need, there is no ambiguity, although i suppose it may make it clearer.

Comment: @123 fair enough, I remember reading something about parentheses being needed in some cases (possibly only on some versions of awk). Anyway I added a similar solution to my answer, based on your suggestion.

Comment: Actually i think your right, i remember Ed morton, master of awk mentioning something a while ago. Your way is a lot clearer so probably better anyway :)